# Is it possible to change the theme of a slide to predefined themes in Power Point using office js?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am working on an add-in for Power Point and if the current theme is default theme then I want to change the theme to other predefined theme.

I tried to Google and search from the documentation but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are talking about the themes inside PowerPoint, not the Office Themes or the operating system themes. In that case, there isn't any way of controlling the PowerPoint theme of a slide in PowerPoint add-ins. There is a way that you can insert a slide from another presentation into the current presentation. See [Insert slides](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/insert-slides-into-presentation). If your add-in users will have access to another presentation that has a slide with the theme you want, you could programmatically insert that slide and then programmatically add content to it.

Otherwise, take a look at this article, [Use document themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/use-document-themes-in-your-powerpoint-add-ins), and the [OfficeTheme interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.officetheme) API to see if they help you achieve your scenario.